# Unable to use Ionicons in react native app

Tags: react-native, expo, ionicons

I'm trying to use Ionicons on react-native app using expo, unfortunately the icon is not showing and the following error is received:

> fontFamily "ionicons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.
>
> - If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.
> - If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.

I'm using Iocincons in the following way:

```
import { Ionicons }  from '@expo/vector-icons';

....

<Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={24} color="black" />
```

In addition, this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1",
    "expo-font": "^9.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.18.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I've already tried to remove node_modules, package-lock.json, and run npm install, but it didn't solved the problem.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: In your code, have you written anywhere like this - `fontFamily: "ionicons"` ?

Comment: No, I've used Ionicons just in the example I provided above. @KartikeyVaish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating expo to version 41 solved this problem.